# Question about support of some resources via ARM

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, appsource

I am about to publish an app on Azure Market Place and **I am trying** to create a "Test drive".
My application is based on several Azure resources :

- App Service (webapp + api)
- Azure search index
- Azure storage
- SQL Database
- PowerBI Embedded

My question is: Are these resources all supported via ARM? 
(especially the creation of an azure search index and PowerBI Embedded "linked" to a PowerBI account)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources except `Azure search index` are all supported via ARM.(Azure search service is supported)

For the ARM templates of them, you could refer to the `Reference` in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/). Also, in the portal, you could check them when you creating the resource in `Automation options` of the creation blade after filling the properties.

Comment: Do we have any idea if MS planning to support `Azure search index` ?

Comment: @T.G. May be you could track [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?status=indevelopment), besides I recommend you to post the idea in the [Azure search feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) or [ARM feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager).

Comment: Thanks. It's done: [feedback azure](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/35737618-azure-search-index-arm-template-support)